# d3.json callback function

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, callback

I'm using d3.js 3.4.13, and the docs say the callback function for `d3.json(data, callback)` should be of the format `callback(error, responseData)`, however, I found that it actually sets the data to the first parameter, and the second parameter is unnecessary, so I use `callback(responseData)` instead.  It works, but I'm confused why it doesn't work the same way I interpreted the docs to describe it.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at [the source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/xhr/xhr.js) reveals the following function:

```
function d3_xhr_fixCallback(callback) {
  return callback.length === 1
      ? function(error, request) { callback(error == null ? request : null); }
      : callback;
}
```

D3 explicitly checks the number of arguments to the callback through `.length` and if there's only one, puts the data in it.

So the one-argument version is a convenience version that still works as expected.

Comment: quick follow up...any idea on why it set my data to the first argument, and not the second, when I use the two argument version?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Do you have a concrete example?